# Proving that $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(re^{it})|^2dt=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^2r^{2n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ with radius of convergence equals to $R$. Show that for every $r<R$:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(re^{it})|^2dt=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^2r^{2n}$$

I tried this:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(re^{it})|^2dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(re^{it})\overline{f(re^{it})}dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nr^ne^{int}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\overline{a_n}r^ne^{-int}dt=
\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}}a_k\overline{a_{n-k}}r^ne^{int}$$

But this is about it. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware of the relationship that $\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{i(n-m)t} = 2\pi\delta_{nm}$, where $\delta_{nm}$ is the Kronecker delta? Also you _really_ need to use different indices for your sums. Make one an index over $n$ and the other an index over $m$. The two sums are separate from each other so you should demonstrate this with different indices. It doesn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: This is a restatement of Parseval's theorem for holomorphic functions on the disk if you're familiar with Fourier theory.

Comment: Your last line is not correct. Using different indices in the line before (as suggested by Cameron), say $n$ and $m$, and permuting $\Sigma$ and $\int$, you should get $\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty a_n\overline{a_m} r^{n+m} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(n-m)t}dt$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \int_0^{2\pi}| f(re^{it})|^2 dt = \int_0^{2\pi}f(re^{it})\overline{f(re^{it})}dt = \int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nr^ne^{int}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\overline{a_m}r^me^{-imt} dt $$

Assuming we can commute the sums (which I guess you could argue from uniform convergence of the power series) we have

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}| f(re^{it})|^2 dt = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_n\overline{a_m}r^{n+m}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(n-m)t}dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_n\overline{a_m}r^{n+m} 2\pi\delta_{nm} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^2r^{2n}.$$

As for how to so that $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(n-m)t}dt = 2\pi\delta_{nm}$, the proof is as follows:

Suppose $n = m$ then we wish to evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(n-m)t}dt = \int_0^{2\pi}e^{0}dt = \int_0^{2\pi} 1 dt = 2\pi$.

Suppose $n\neq m$ then we have $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(n-m)t} dt = \frac{1}{i(n-m)}e^{i(n-m)t}|_0^{2\pi} = \frac{1}{i(n-m)}\left(e^{2\pi i(n-m)} - 1\right)$. But since $2\pi i(n-m)$ is a multiple of $2\pi$, $e^{2\pi i(n-m)} = 1$ and so it evaluates to $0$. QED.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. For completeness I will write the answer:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(re^{it})|^2dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(re^{it})\overline{f(re^{it})}dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nr^ne^{int}\right) \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\overline{a_n}r^ne^{-int}\right) dt=
\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}}a_k\overline{a_{n-k}}r^ne^{i(2k-n)t}dt=
{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}}a_k\overline{a_{n-k}}r^n\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i(2k-n)t}dt=
2\pi\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n/2}\overline{a_{n/2}}r^n=2\pi\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_{n}|^2r^{2n}$$

Comment: Again, you really need to use different indices for your summations. What you have written doesn't really make sense. I will write it out an an answer since you kind of have the idea.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Thanks a lot. About the indices - I get what you're saying but I'm used to this notation. I've added brackets - does it make it clearer?

Comment: I understand but you cannot repeat indices like that because it can lead to erroneous results. What you have done in your fourth term in the series of equalities is effectively discount all of the values of $k > n$ so you have considered only about half of your overall state space for $(n,k)$. If you want to look at your state space of $(n,k)$ like a matrix, you basically only looked at the lower triangular part of the matrix. In this case it worked out because the only values that mattered lied along the diagonal but in general this is not true.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: How is what I did different from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product ?

Comment: I didn't realize you were using the Cauchy product. Then what you have is fine. But I am going to make an edit to the Wikipedia article because they shouldn't be reusing indices like they are. It is not proper mathematical form.